# Tuple of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, tuples

Suppose I have the following tuple:

```
Tuple<IEnumerable<object1>, IEnumerable<object2>> tp;
```

If I iterate through Item2, how can I get the matching pair from Item1?
Something like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < tp.Item2.Count(); i++)
 {
    //Is tp.Item1.ElementAt(i) the pair for tp.Item2.ElementAt(i) ? 
 }
```

EDIT: Suppose Item1 is a IEnumerable which contains file names and Item2 is a IEnumerable which records how many times a pattern was found in the file name.
So, Item1 will always have at least one element but Item2 might or might not have any elements. If we do have elements in Item2, how to match them to Item1?

Comment: `IEnumerable` doesn't have indexer access. Also, what about the situation, when both enumerables have the different count?

Comment: What about `tp.Item2.Intersect(tp.Item1)`(not tested)?

Comment: if it's a pair than why don't you use `IEnumerable<Tuple<object1, object2>>` first?

Comment: @Selvin Because the sizes are different. Think of a file name in one IEnumerable and in the second IEnumerable are the parsing errors.

Comment: @mb14 - If the sizes are different then how do you line up the values in the two `IEnumerable` instances?

Comment: @mb14 if the sizes of the list are different there is no way to relate them. what would be the common ground? instead you could design around this, just insert null/0 or some dummy value into the list if there are no values, so the count of both lists are equal

Comment: @mb14 another option is instead of adding values that are missing from one list to the other list is to ofcourse omit the values all together. E.g. if you have no parsing errors in list2, then you can choose to not add the file name to list1 - depending on what you use the list for ofcourse. Anyways i feel like this question needs more context and you should add some

Comment: Answer by @Sean will work for enumerables with different sizes. It will skip elements which have no matching elements in other enumerable. You should clarify in your question if that is what you want

Comment: Why this strange implementation? Why not have a class with two properties FileName and Errors. Than you have an IEnumerable<T> of that class.

Comment: @Magnus Tis just fate :))

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Enumerable.Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8) to group the items into a tuple and then enumerate over it:

```
var pairs = tp.Item2.Zip(tp.Item1, (first, second) => (first, second));
foreach(var (first, second) in pairs)
{
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < tp.Item1.Count(); i++)
 {
    var list2 = tp.Item2.ToList();
    var item2 = list2[i];
 }
```

although it would be more performant to iterate the ienumerable to a list beforehand:

```
 var list2 = tp.Item2.ToList();

 for (int i = 0; i < tp.Item1.Count(); i++)
 {
    var item2 = list2[i];
 }
```

You could also do this instead;

```
var items = new List<Tuple<object, object>>();

foreach(var (item1, item2) in items)
{
    // Do something with item1 and item2
}
```

Comment: What about case, when the count of both items are different?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski you do something else - but that is not specified in the question

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes, that is the case, that is why the structure of the data is Tuple<IEnumerable, IEnumerable>

Comment: Have a look at the last comment from OP under the question